# How to avoid returning const-ref to a temporary in a cache

Tags: c++, caching, maps

I have a simple object cache:

```
class ObjectCache
{
public:
    ObjectCache() {}

    const Object& object(const std::string &key) const
    {
        auto it = cache_.find(key);
        if (it != cache_.end())
        {
            return it->second;
        }

        return Object(); // const-ref to temporary
    }

    void insert(const std::string &key, const Object &object)
    {
        cache_[key] = object;
    }

private:
    std:map<std::string, Object> cache_;
};
```

The return type is when retrieving from the cache is a const ref.

However, in the case the key is not found, a const ref to a temporary is returned and results in undefined behaviour for calling code.

How can I address the issue of returning a const ref to a temporary?

Some thoughts I've had:

- Insert and return pointers (cache takes ownership), nullptr means not found
- Provide ObjectCache::contains so calling code can check before accessing
- Maintain either a static or empty Object member and return a reference to that when not found

Comment: you already list 3 options, what is wrong with them? It primarily depends on how calling code is supposed to look like and if the default object should be a new one each time it is returned or the same

Comment: All three options are equally valid IMO. The second one (with a `constains` function) is prone to thread data-races though.

Comment: A fourth solution is to use `std::optional` or `booost::optiona` to wrap the reference.

Comment: You could use std::optional.

Comment: Regarding the first option. Just because the `object` function returns by pointer it doesn't mean the `insert` has to take a pointer. The `insert` can still take by copy but the `object` can return nullptr to mean not found.

Comment: Don't use pointers in C++. Contains doesn't solve the problem; what If they call anyway? Use the default object.

Comment: Option 5) throw a `ItemNotFoundException` if the object is not found.  Option 6) make the class iterable and return `end()` if not found else an iterator to the object.

Comment: Use `std::optional`.

Comment: I don't see real benefit of `optional` over pointer here.

Comment: To everybody saying "use `std::optional`": C++17's `optional` cannot hold references (though `boost::optional` can), so a raw pointer would be better here.

Comment: Of course `std::optional` can hold references. That's what `std::ref` is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal solution is to maintain the current cache but return a pointer to a reference:

```
class ObjectCache
{
public:
    ObjectCache() {}

    const Object* object(const std::string &key) const
    {
        auto it = cache_.find(key);
        if (it != cache_.end())
        {
            return &(it->second);
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    void insert(const std::string &key, const Object &object)
    {
        cache_[key] = object;
    }

private:
    std:map<std::string, Object> cache_;
};
```

This has the added benefit of avoiding creating objects on the heap and memory management but allows calling code to work with a nullptr as not found.

Answer (score 0):

You could offer an interface that allows the caller express the desired behaviour:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct Object {};

struct NoObject : std::logic_error
{
    using std::logic_error::logic_error;

};

class ObjectCache
{
public:
    ObjectCache() {}

    /// Require an object for the corresponding key
    /// @param key
    /// @exception NoObject if the key does not represent an object
    ///  in cache
    const Object& require(const std::string &key) const
    {
        auto it = cache_.find(key);
        if (it != cache_.end())
        {
            return it->second;
        }
        throw NoObject(key);
    }

    /// return the object corresponding to key if it exists
    /// If not, call the factory function, store the result and return
    /// the corresponding object
    template<class Factory>
    const Object& acquire(const std::string &key, Factory&& factory) 
    {
        auto it = cache_.find(key);
        if (it == cache_.end())
        {
            it = cache_.emplace(key, factory(key)).first;
        }
        return it->second;
    }


    /// Return the object corresponding to key if it exists.    
    boost::optional<const Object&> query(const std::string &key) const
    {
        auto it = cache_.find(key);
        if (it != cache_.end())
        {
            return it->second;
        }
        else
        {
            return {};
        }
    }

    void insert(const std::string &key, const Object &object)
    {
        cache_[key] = object;
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, Object> cache_;
};

int main()
{
    ObjectCache cache;

    // fetch existing or create
    auto& x = cache.acquire("foo", [](std::string const& key){
        return Object();
    });

    // fetch existing or exception
    auto& y = cache.require("foo");

    // fetch existing if exists
    if(auto z = cache.query("foo"))
    {
        auto&& zz = z.get();
    }

}
```